# Combining modular congruencies

Tags: modular-arithmetic, contest-math

I'm trying to work through the PuMaC 2016 a-division algebra contest, but I'm having trouble understanding the solution for #4.

The solution shows that there is an integer $N$ where

- $N = 2 \pmod{2015}$
- $N = 3 \pmod{2014}$
- $N = 3 \pmod{2013}$

Then it skips to

$N = 3 + 1007 \times 2013 \times 2014 \pmod{2013 \times 2014 \times 2015}$

I'm just a bit confused how they got to that step? If I didn't add enough detail to my question, here's the contest archive I got it from: https://jason-shi-f9dm.squarespace.com/archives/#2016

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

$N=3+\lambda\times2013\times2014$ clearly satisfies two of the equations. You then need $$2=3+\lambda\times2013\times2014\pmod{2015}$$$$2014=\lambda\times(-2)\times(-1)\pmod{2015}$$

Therefore $\lambda=1007$ is a solution.